# Problema login Java y MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, mvc, login

hoy vengo con ustedes porque me surgio un problema con un login que estoy haciendo en Java con conexion a BD MYSQL.

Mi clase conexion:

```
public class Conexion {
Connection conectar = null;
    public Connection conexion(){ 
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            System.out.println("Registrado");
            System.out.println("");

            conectar=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/matematicas?" + "useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&user=root&password=Csgo1997" );
        } catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex + "Error en la conexion");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
         return conectar;  
    }

    public void cerrarConexion(){
       try {
           conectar.close();
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
       }
    }
```

}

Ahora, el metodo que uso para el boton de "logueo"

```
private void validar() {
    //FIXME: Arreglar este metodo porque no entra a BD
Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
conexion.conexion();
    Connection connection = null;
    int resultado = 0;

    try {
        String usuario = txtUsuario.getText();
        String pass = String.valueOf(txtPassword.getPassword());

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM profesor WHERE usuario = '" + usuario + "' and password = '" + pass + "' ";
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        if(resultset.next()){
            resultado = 1;

            if (resultado == 1) {
                ventanaOpcionesProfesor voProfesor = new ventanaOpcionesProfesor();
                voProfesor.setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, vuelve a intentarlo");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Error en el codigo, metodo validar "  +  e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer no entra a la consulta sql, se va de largo al catch y me marca ese error. Llevo varios dias intentando solucionarlo pero, no doy con el error. ¿Alguna idea de lo que pueda estar pasando?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/258067/3834

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás usando una clase que no hereda los métodos de la clase Connection. Mi sugerencia es convertir el método `public Connection conexion()` en un [método estático](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2015/09/17/la-directiva-static-en-java/), o inicializar la conexión directamente desde la función `validar()`.

```
public class Conexion {
    private static Connection conectar = null;
    public static Connection conexion(){ 
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            System.out.println("Registrado");
            System.out.println("");

            Connection conectar = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/matematicas?" + "useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&user=root&password=Csgo1997" );
        } catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex + "Error en la conexion");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conectar;  
    }

    public static void cerrarConexion(){
         try {
             conectar.close();
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace(); 
         }
    }
}
```

Debés tener cuidado con las instancias de las clases, así como la herencia de métodos y propiedades.

Comment: He cambiado como me has recomendado, sin embargo me aparece otro detalle en la linea   Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

Comment: Asegurate de quitar la línea `Connection connection = null;`

Comment: Si, la linea ya ha sido quitada, me marca un error en el connection createStatement la cual me dice "No se encuentra el metodo createStatement en tu clase Conexion" ¿Alguna solucion del porque ese problema?

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta