# ¿Cómo hacer mi login con ajax, jsp y servlets?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

Estoy tratando de hacer un login sencillo usando `servlets`, `jquery` y `ajax`, pero no encuentro la forma que me funcione.

Adjunto mi código para que me puedan ayudar, he intentando de varias formas pero nada aun.La conexión a la BD si se da, pude ingresar solo con código `JSP` y se pudo. Pero ahora estoy intentado usar `Ajax`, ya que planeo aprender mas cosas sobre como usarlo en un futuro. Muchas gracias.

La base está en `MySQL`. Es solo una tabla sencilla, pero que servirá para más adelante. No sé que más poner porque me dice que hay poca descripción así que uso este texto como relleno para ver si me deja publicar xd, no se debería tener esa restricción puesto que se puede explicar bien sin mucho texto, pero asumo que es la lógica de la web.

```
/*Clase con la conexión a BD y métodos*/
public class BDLoginSistema {

    private String Driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    private String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proyajax?useSSL=false";
    private String Usuario = "root";
    private String Password = "mysql";

    private Connection Cn;
    private CallableStatement cstm;
    private ResultSet rs;

    public BDLoginSistema() {
        try {
            Class.forName(Driver);
            Cn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,Usuario,Password);
        } 

        catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.print("**********************ERROR " +e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public boolean Login(String usr, String pwd){
        String SQL = "CALL usp_login(?,?);";
        try {
            cstm = Cn.prepareCall(SQL);
            cstm.setString(1, usr);
            cstm.setString(2, pwd);
            rs = cstm.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                return true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.print("************ERROR EN LOGIN" + e.getMessage());
        }
      return false;  
    }

}

/*Servlet Java*/
 @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try { 
        NegocioLogin ObjNL = new NegocioLogin();
        String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

         boolean flagLogin = ObjNL.Login(usuario, password);

        if(flagLogin == true){
             response.setContentType("text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
             out.write("menuIngreso");
        } else{
            response.setContentType("text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
            out.write("Error");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*Index.jsp*/
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="js/validarLogin.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <form class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Ingrese por Favor</h2>
        <div id="errorLogin">

        </div>
        <br>
        <label for="inputUsuario" class="sr-only">Usuario</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputUsuario" name="inputUsuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="Enviar">Ingresar</button>
      </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>

/*Archivo .JS con la función Ajax.*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Enviar').click(function(){
       var user =$('#inputUsuario').val();
       var pwd = $('#inputPassword').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "servletLogin",
            data: {"usuario" : user, "password" : pwd},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == 'menuIngreso') {
                    var url = 'menuIngreso.html';
                    window.location.href = url;
                } else {
                    $("#errorLogin").html(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: En efecto, era necesario explicar mejor sin relleno. ¿Qué error te sale? Por favor incluye el texto del error **como texto y no como imagen**.

Comment: En este caso, no valida nada. No es que salga ningun error, solamente permite enviar los datos del formulario sin validar. Como mención, los datos del usuario y password, cuando se le da enviar, pasan a la URL.

Comment: Llega al servlet? Si es así, qué validación quieres aplicar? en el doPost se ve que recibes las variables y haces el login. Qué te falta?

Comment: Algo me dice que no está llegando al Servlet. Puesto que, cuando el login es efectivo, debe redirigir a mi pagina menuIngreso.html. En caso la validación falle, debe pintar mi div con id = errorLogin con la palabra "Error"

Comment: ese doPost no esta haciendo ninguna redirección. Todo indica que necesitas implementar un filter para redirigir la petición de acuerdo a la validación que necesites

Comment: Pero, el Ajax no se encarga de hacer la redirección en este caso? Ya que es por eso que lo estoy aplicando ahí

Comment: Tienes TODA la razón. Revisa en la consola del navegador si sale la respuesta que recibe el llamado ajax.

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/servlet/ajax/login.html

Comment: Haciendo seguimiento en la consola veo que cuando no ingreso datos si me sale el alert(modifiqué el mensaje de error) y si ejecuta la llamada XMLHttpRequest, pero cuando ya ingreso datos en los inputs y apreto el boton, no se realiza la ejecucion de eso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paso numero 1: Crear un archivo **login.jsp** (Lo siento si lo quieres mas simple tendras que quitar el bootstrap).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset='UTF-8'">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesBootstrap/bootstrap-superhero-dorado.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../webjars/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="j_security_check" method="post"> <!--ES MUY IMPORTANTE QUE EL ACCION SE LLAME ASI-->
        <div class="container"><!-- Permite centrar el contenido -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"> &nbsp; </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"> &nbsp; </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"> &nbsp; </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-primary" >
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2 class="panel-title"><label>Iniciar sesión:</label> </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">        
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 center">
                            <label>Usuario:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9 center">
                            <input name="j_username" /><!--ES MUY IMPORTANTE QUE LA CAJA DE TEXTO DEL USUARIO SE LLAME ASI-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12"> &nbsp; </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 center">
                            <label>Contraseña:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9 center">
                            <input name="j_password" type="password"/> <!--ES MUY IMPORTANTE QUE LA CAJA DE TEXTO DEL PASSWORD SE LLAME ASI-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12"> &nbsp; </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 center">
                            <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión" class="btn btn-primary btn-ld" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
       </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Paso No 2: En el archivo **web.xml** agrega las opciones de seguridad:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Secured context</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Consultas de Cheques</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/rutaAproteger/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>usuario</role-name><!--Roles permitidos a esta rutaAproteger-->
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method> <!--Metodo de autenticacion por formulario-->
    <realm-name>RealmConfiguradoParaEstaAplicacion</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page><!--Estos archivos estan fuera de la ruta a proteger-->
      <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name><!--Roles que se usaran en esta aplicacion-->
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>usuario</role-name>
  </security-role>
```

Paso 3: Crea el archivo **error.jsp**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset='UTF-8'">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesBootstrap/bootstrap-superhero-dorado.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../webjars/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.jsp">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"> &nbsp; </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"> &nbsp; </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"> &nbsp; </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-white bg-danger col-mb-8">
               <div class="card-header">Usuario no autenticado</div>
               <div class="card-body">
                 <h4 class="card-title">Aviso:</h4>
                 <p class="card-text">El usuario y/o contraseña no es(son) valido(s). Favor de verificar</p>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Ir al inicio de sesión</button>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Paso 4: Crea el **index.jsp** (Aqui hay un truco; el index.jsp invoca a un servlet que tiene el path /rutaAproteger para que el web.xml lo proteja). Este archivo siempre sera la entrada a tu aplicación:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"  %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset='UTF-8'">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=rutaAproteger/CrearSesion">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Paso 5: Crea el Servlet para crear la sesión:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
@WebServlet("/rutaAproteger/CrearSesion")
public class CrearSesion extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public CrearSesion(){
        super();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println( request.getRemoteUser());
        Principal p=request.getUserPrincipal();
        
        String nextJSP = "";
        if(p!=null){
            System.out.println("Usuario autenticado: "+p.getName());
            System.out.println("Rol admin: "+request.isUserInRole("admin"));
            System.out.println("Rol usuario: "+request.isUserInRole("usuario"));
            nextJSP = "/rutaAproteger/home.jsp";
            HttpSession sesion=request.getSession(true);
            sesion.setAttribute("usuario",p.getName());
        }else {
            System.out.println("Usuario no autenticado.");
            nextJSP = "index.jsp";
        }
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Paso 6: Crea la ruta a proteger. Es decir crea una carpeta **/rutaAproteger** y dentro un archivo por ejemplo **home.jsp**. En home.jsp comprueba que en la sesión ya tienes acceso al usuario logueado. Aqui en este archivo es donde empieza la logica de tu aplicacion, lo anterior fue la logica del login:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset='UTF-8'">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    home.jsp
    ${sessionScope.usuario}
</body>
</html>
```

Paso 7: Enlaza el [REALM](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/realm-howto.html) configurado en el web.xml con tomcat. Para ello agrega el realm siguiente en el archivo **server.xml** de tomcat. De esta forma tienes acceso a la base de datos. Quien protege la aplicación es tomcat, solo permite acceso a los roles de base de datos que contiene el realm. Pero tu aplicacion tambien debe saber que roles son, es por ello que los pones de nuevo en el web.xml:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm" resourceName="RealmConfiguradoParaEstaAplicacion">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" connectionName="tuUsuarioBD" connectionPassword="password" connectionURL="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=NombreBaseDatos;" debug="2" driverName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" roleNameCol="rol" userCredCol="password" userNameCol="usuario" userRoleTable="usuariorol" userTable="usuario"/>
      </Realm>
```

Paso 8. Crea la base de datos (Es muy importante que las llaves de la tabla donde estan los usuarios y la tabla de roles sean varchar, si no jamas funcionara):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Explicación: Cuando carga la aplicación se lee la configuración de seguridad del **web.xml**. Tu punto de entrada es **index.jsp**. Al invocarlo se refresca y busca el servlet **/rutaAproteger/CrearSesion**. Pero como dijiste en **web.xml** que solo los roles usuario y admin tienen acceso ahi te manda a login.jsp. En login.jsp (configurado en web.xml) tu tienes un **action j_password** y las cajas de texto de **usuario (j_username)** y **contraseña (j_password)**, es muy importante que se llamen asi porque asi java indentifica que ese es un jsp especial de login y por eso nunca podras invocarlo directamente. Cuando ingresas usuario y contraseña y das clic en el boton va a consultar el [**realm** (domino de seguridad)](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/realm-howto.html) **RealmConfiguradoParaEstaAplicacion** configurado en tomcat. El tomcat se conecta a la base de datos y busca en la tabla **userTable** la columna **userNameCol** y la columna **userCredCol** para saber que el usuario tiene las credenciales. Tambien busca en la tabla **userRoleTable** la tabla de enmedio de la relación si existe el rol en la columna **roleNameCol**. Para eso debes insertar los roles **usuario** y **admin** en la tabla roles y un usuario **fulanito** con su **contraseña** en la tabla de usuarios. Y por ultimo un registro en la tabla de enmedio de la relación para decir que **fulanito** tiene **X(usuario o admin)** rol. Entonces compara las credenciales de tu usuario en BD con las que diste en el login, si la comparación falla la configuración del **web.xml** te manda a **error.jsp**. Si es correcto tienes acceso al servlet **/rutaAproteger/CrearSesion** que fue lo que invocaste. Lo que hace el servlet es sacar del Principal (usuario+rol) los datos he imprimir que rol tiene el usuario con el que te logueaste y guardarlos en el HttpSession. Después te redirige a una pagina /rutaAproteger/home.jsp donde iniciaras el desarrollo de tu aplicación. Todo lo que quieres que proteja el login debe estar dentro de **/rutaAproteger** y los archivos **index.jsp, login.jsp y error.jsp** deben estar al mismo nivel de **/rutaAproteger**. El único que esta dentro es **home.jsp**. El driver que tiene el Realm es de SQL server cambiaselo por el de mysql. Si te das cuenta solo ocupe ajax jquery para bootstrap, porque en realidad no se necesita para el login y la sesión, todo lo resuelve java.

Por ultimo puedes crear un servlet **CerrarSesion** que recupere la HttpSession, la destruya con session.invalidate y te redireccione a index.jsp. Este servlet lo llamarias desde algun boton en algun menu:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
@WebServlet("/consultas/CerrarSesion")
public class CerrarSesion extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public CerrarSesion() {
        super();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession sesion=request.getSession();
        sesion.invalidate();
        String nextJSP="index.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Casi todos los conceptos los saque de este libro [SEGURIDAD EN APLICACIONES WEB JAVA](http://www.ra-ma.es/libros/SEGURIDAD-EN-APLICACIONES-WEB-JAVA/98403/978-84-9964-732-6), aunque la logica fue parte de mi ingenio y de algunos de mis compañeros de trabajo.

**Actualización 09/Nov/2021:** Hace tiempo realice esta [misma en lógica en glassfish](http://jugojava.blogspot.com/2011/02/jdbc-security-realm-with-glassfish-and.html) y descubrí que es posible que los ids de las tablas pueden ser enteros, pero para que funcione en tomcat hay que crear una vista similar a esta:

```
CREATE VIEW `v_user_role` AS
SELECT  u.username, u.password, g.group_name
 FROM `user_groups` ug
 INNER JOIN `users` u ON u.user_id = ug.user_id
 INNER JOIN `groups` g ON g.group_id =  ug.group_id;
```

y por lo tanto en el paso 7 que es la configuración del realm las siguientes propiedades apuntarían a la vista y no a las tablas:

```
userRoleTable="usuariorol" userTable="usuario"
```

De esta forma se logra un mejor rendimiento ya que los ids son enteros y sin llaves compuestas ni campos varchar como marcan las [buenas practicas de base de datos](https://inmensia.com/blog/20070223/elegir_clave_primaria_tabla_base_datos_oracle.html).

**Actualización 01/Feb/2023:** *En el paso 7 es mejor colocar la configuración del REALM en el archivo context.xml de tomcat.* La decisión de si el archivo debe estar en el servidor de tomcat o en el contexto de tu aplicación depende de varias cosas, principalmente del método de conexión, eso ya depende de cada aplicación.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!