# Tengo un problema con las consultas en Hibernate

Tags: java, jsp, hibernate

Estoy cambiando mi aplicacion para hacer las consultas con hibernate pero en el metodo autenticacion nose como hacerlo para que me devuelva un boolean si el query es correcto.

Este metodo recibe el usuario y contraseña y devuelve true o false dependiendo si lo ha encontrado o no pero nose como acabarlo. Gracias.

Registrar me funciona, los demás metodos no.

```
public class UsuarioDao {
public boolean registrar(String apellido, String usuario, String nombre, String pass ) {
    // Añade un objeto nuevo a la base de datos (persistencia)
    Session session = HibernateManager.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction(); // Crea una transaccion
    Usuario a = new Usuario();

    a.setApellido(apellido);
    a.setUsuario(usuario);
    a.setNombre(nombre);
    a.setPass(pass);
    session.save(a); // Guarda el objeto creado en la BBDD
    tx.commit(); // Materializa la transaccion
    session.close();
    return true;
}

public static boolean autenticacion(String usuario, String pass) {


    Session session = HibernateManager.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction(); // Crea una transaccion
    session.createQuery("FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario and pass = :pass");

    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    return false;

}
public static Usuario obtenerUsuarioNombre(String usuario) {

    Session session = HibernateManager.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction(); // Crea una transaccion
    Usuario usr;
    usr = (Usuario) session.createQuery("FROM Usuario WHERE usuario = " + usuario);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();


    return usr;




}
```

Comment: No entiendo: Te quieres conectar a `hibernate` o quieres hacer un `login` a tu aplicación usando `hibernate`?? Creo que es lo segundo. Otra pregunta, tu aplicación es web o de escritorio??

Comment: Quiero hacer un metodo que me autentique un usuario en una aplicacion web, tengo el metodo registro que me funciona pero el metodo autenticar y buscar por nombre no se como hacerlos y me estot volviendo loca...

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer un `loguin` no necesitas `hibernate` ya que los servidores de aplicaciones tienen configuraciones especiales para proteger tu aplicación y que tengas sistemas de AUTENTICACION y AUTORIZACION. Estas configuraciones se llaman `REALMS`. Por otra parte si usas `hibernate` puedes hacer que convivan los [REALMS](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html) con `hibernate` con algo de ingenio.

Para hacer un `loguin` [necesitas seguir estos pasos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/258067/3834). Para hacer que conviva tu sistema de `login` con `hibernate` solo cambia el paso 7 del link que acabo de poner.

En vez de crear en el archivo `server.xml` de `tomcat`, ve a tu aplicación y en la carpeta **META-INF**(No confundir con WEB-INF) crea un archivo **context.xml** y ahí dentro crearas un `resource` que es la configuración de conexión a la base de datos. Después ahí mismo creas un `DataSourceRealm` que utilice ese `resource`. Al final el archivo se vera así(Nota: es te ejemplo se conecta a sql server):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>      
    <Resource name="jdbc/pool" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"  
        maxTotal="50" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="10" maxActive="5"  maxWait="7000" 
        username="usuario" password="password" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=miBaseDeDatos;integratedSecurity=false;" />

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm" dataSourceName="jdbc/pool" 
        roleNameCol="rol" userCredCol="password" userNameCol="usuario" userRoleTable="cheques.usuariorol" userTable="cheques.usuario" localDataSource="true"/>
</Context>
```

Una vez hecho esto apunta la configuración del web.xml al DataSourceRealm asi:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method> <!--Metodo de autenticacion por formulario-->
    <realm-name>pool</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page><!--Estos archivos estan fuera de la ruta a proteger-->
      <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
```

Eso ya lo explicaba el link, pero aquí el truco es que también agregues en el **web.xml** al final el `realm` así:

```
<resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/pool</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

Con esto ya debe funcionar el `loguin`, por lo que solo queda apuntar `hibernate` al **realm** también, y eso se hace del siguiente modo en **hibernate.cfg.xml**:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:/comp/env/jdbc/pool</property>
```

Se que esto no es lo que esperabas, pero esta es la forma correcta de hacer un `loguin`.

Si esto se te hace muy complejo puedes aplicar este hql `select count(u) FROM usuarios u WHERE u.usuario = :usuario and u.pass = :pass`, si regresa 0 no lo encontró y si regresa 1 o mas si lo encontró, y eso puede servirte a manera de condición booleana.

```
Query queryUsuario = session.createQuery("select count(u) FROM usuarios u WHERE u.usuario = :usuario and u.pass = :pass");
queryUsuario.setParameter("user","usuario");
queryUsuario.setParameter("pass","password");
int nousuarios=(int)queryUsuario.uniqueResult();
```