# Restringir acceso a un JSP, sin haber pasado por un LOGIN

Tags: java, jsp

Hola como están? Consulta. Tengo un jsp de login la cual se van a acceder 2 tipos.. administrador o usuario, quiero que vallan a jsp distintos, como hago para restringir los jsp redirigidos sin haber pasado por un login?

```
<div class="formulario">
        <h2>Iniciar Sesion</h2>
        <form action="login.jsp" method="post">
            Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password">  
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Iniciar Sesion">
        </form>
    </div>

    <%
        if (request.getParameter("enviar") != null) {

            Persona p = null;
            ConexionJDBC conn = new ConexionJDBC();
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            p = conn.logear(username, password);

            if (p.getEstado().equals("administrador")) {
                session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("user", p.getUser());
                session.setAttribute("pass", p.getPass());
                response.sendRedirect("indexUsuario.jsp");
            } else if (p.getEstado().equals("usuario")) {
                 session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("user", p.getUser());
                session.setAttribute("pass", p.getPass());
                response.sendRedirect("indexAdministrador.jsp");
            }
        }
```

Comment: ¿Como piensas saber si entra un administrador o un usuario?

Comment: Por que lo estoy conectando con una base de datos MYSQL

Comment: Eso no responde mi pregunta.

Comment: No entiendo.. disculpa, en mi MYSQL tengo una tabla la cual contiene cuenta, password, y estado(administrador o usuario).. y en mi jsp de login mediante codigo java tengo mi logica.

Comment: El usuario no entra directo a una base de datos, entra a una pagina en un jsp. Desde el jsp ¿Como piensas saber si entra un administrador o un usuario?

Comment: Es un ejercicio que estoy haciendo, que le estoy pegando a mi tabla de mysql.. quiero obtener los datos desde esa tabla. No lo estoy pensando de la manera que me lo decis por que no es algo que va a salir a la luz,, es solo practica. Perdon si me exprese mal.

Answer (score 0):

[Esta es la forma correcta de hacer una pagina de loguin en java.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/258067/3834) Cuando alguien entra a una pagina esa persona es `anónima`, hasta que le dice a la pagina `quien es`, mediante un `usuario`. Esta persona podría estar mintiendo, por eso la pagina necesita preguntarle al usuario algo que confirme que realmente es esa persona. Ese algo es la `contraseña`. Una vez que es proporcionada la contraseña el sistema puede saber a que paginas tiene acceso la persona que ingresa mediante los `roles` asignados cuando se creo el `usuario`. Ahí es donde puede tener roles de `Admin` y `User`.

Es hasta que se efectúa un `loguin` que un sistema sabe quien entra y a que paginas tiene acceso el `usuario` que entro. Por eso lo que quieres hacer es imposible. Por eso te preguntaba en los comentarios `¿Como piensas saber si entra un administrador o un usuario?` y tus respuestas me dejaron saber que no tenias ni idea. Lo que si te puedo decir es que es forzoso pasar por un `loguin`.

Una vez hecho un `loguin` ya tienes asignados los `roles`. Al `loguin` se le conoce como `Autenticación` y a lo que se le permite ver se le conoce como `Autorización`. La `autorización` se realiza mediante `roles`.El sistema pregunta que `rol` tiene este `usuario` y en base a ello le da el acceso (autorización).

Si haces el `loguin` como esta en el link que te puse, ocultar una pagina de administración del resto se vuelve muy sencillo. En el paso 6 del link viene que tienes que crear un archivo **home.jsp**. Es ahí donde va el código que necesitas. Si el usuario tiene rol `Admin` lo mandas a la pagina de `administración`, pero si tiene `rol` `User` lo mandas a una pagina normal. En la pagina **home.jsp** pondrías un código similar a esto:

```
<c:if test="<%=request.isUserInRole("admin")%>">
    <jsp:forward page="/administracion.jsp"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="<%= !request.isUserInRole("admin")%>">
    <jsp:forward page="/normal.jsp"/>
</c:if>
```

Te lo repito, sin un loguin es imposible.