# ¿Cómo almacenar valores de un Login en Java?

Tags: java, mysql, almacenamiento

Quiero que al hacer Login los valores del resultado de la consulta `MySQL` se almacenen para consultas posteriores, por ejemplo utilizar el ID.

Lo anterior lo asocio con el equivalente de `$_SESSION` de PHP

**Código de la Consulta `MySQL`**

```
  public void login(String user, String password) throws SQLException{
    connectionDB();
    try {
        _callableStatment = connDB.prepareCall("{call Login(?,?)}");
        _callableStatment.setString(1, user);
        _callableStatment.setString(2, password);
        _callableStatment.execute();

        _resultSet = _callableStatment.getResultSet();
        while(_resultSet.next()){
            System.out.println(_resultSet.getInt(1)+" "+_resultSet.getString(4));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{
        closeConnectionDB();
    }        

}
```

Lo obtenido en el `_resultSet` es lo que deseo almacenar para futuras consultas.

Comment: Puedes usar un objeto creado con el patrón de diseño Singleton donde mantengas el estado de la sesión.

Comment: @E.Betanzos pudieras poner como respuesta un ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar clase, como esta, que crees con el patrón de diseño [Singleton](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton) en la cual puedes mantener durante la ejecución de todo el programa información de la sesión.

```
public final class Session {
    private static Session session;

    private String loggedUser;

    private Session() {}

    public static Session getCurrentInstance() {
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session();
        }
    }

    public void setLoggedUser(String username) {
        loggedUser = username;
    }

    public String getLoggedUser() {
        return loggedUser;
    }
}


// En tu método de autenticación haces algo como esto que claro está
// depenede de tus necesidades
public void login(String user, String password) throws SQLException{
    connectionDB();
    try {
        _callableStatment = connDB.prepareCall("{call Login(?,?)}");
        _callableStatment.setString(1, user);
        _callableStatment.setString(2, password);
        _callableStatment.execute();

        _resultSet = _callableStatment.getResultSet();
        while(_resultSet.next()){
            System.out.println(_resultSet.getInt(1)+" "+_resultSet.getString(4));
        }

        // Si todo va bien en la autenticación
        Session.getCurrentInstance().setLoggedUser(user);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{
        closeConnectionDB();
    }        

}

// Luego en cualquier parte de tu aplicación donde quieras saber el usuario autenticado haces esto
Session.getCurrentInstance().getLoggedUser()
```

Comment: Eso mismo pudiera servir para pasar parámetros entre modales, en java me sucede que al pasar variables en modales, se produce un bloqueo y no pasa los datos, funcionara para eso?

Comment: Probare el código para marcar la respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: @FernyCortez te puede servir para pasar datos entre ventanas, aunque no es la solución que más me gusta. Prefiero pasar estos datos en el constructor del formulario o usando un método público de este.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que le recomendaría usar sería una clase "**Listener**". Esta clase se ejecuta antes que el resto del proyecto y nos ayudará a crear y/o mantener nuestra sesión activa a lo largo del mismo.

**Pasos para su implementación:**

- (Opcional) Creamos un nuevo paquete para ese tipo de clases, "listeners"
- Click derecho al paquete  → new → Elegimos **Listener**
- Asignamos un nombre y le damos *Next*
- Nos aparecerá una serie de opciones, marcamos ***Lifecycle*** del apartado ***HTTP session events***
- Le damos *Finish*

Tendrás una estructura similar a esta:

```
public class UserListener implements HttpSessionListener {

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public UserListener() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpSessionListener#sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent)
 */
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se)  {

    // Instancio clase de prueba
    Customer c = new Customer();
    // Agrego valores a los atributos
    c.setId(1);
    c.setName("Pablito");
    c.setLastname("Calvito");

    // Establecemos la variable de sesión
    se.getSession().setAttribute("user", c);
}

/**
 * @see HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent)
 */
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se)  { 
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

Trabajaremos en el método `sessionCreated`. Lo que he hecho es una instancia de mi clase de usuario o cliente el cual se mantendrá a lo largo del proyecto. Le asigno valores y posteriormente lo establezco como una variable de sesión. Para establecer el atributo, usaremos el método `setAttribute()`, como primer parámetro el nombre de nuestra variable; y el segundo, nuestra propia variable.

Para este ejemplo, lo aplicaré directamente en un *JSP*, pero lo puede usar en sus métodos, clases o en donde lo requiera:

[image: Ejemplo JSP]

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: no es una aplicación web, es algo mas de escritorio. Se aplican los mismmos conceptos?

Comment: Hola Ferny, debería especificar en la pregunta que es Java escritorio. Pero descuide, esos conceptos no se aplican a escritorio. Lo que podría hacer, es primero instanciar "public static MiClase usuario = metodoQueRetornaUsuario()" antes del método main de su clase principal. Así, ya lo tendría de forma global y podría acceder a ella haciendo algo como "MiClase user = MiClasePrincipal.usuario", el "user" tendría todo los valores que requiere. Espero se me entienda.

Comment: Perfecto y entendido.

Comment: Cualquier duda, nos lo comenta, amigo :D.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada creo que deberías [hacer el loguin con java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/258067/3834) de una forma mas adecuada. Una vez hecho esto observa el **Paso 5: Crea el Servlet para crear la sesión**. Aquí ya tienes todo:

```
if(p!=null){
            System.out.println("Usuario autenticado: "+p.getName());
            System.out.println("Rol admin: "+request.isUserInRole("admin"));
            System.out.println("Rol usuario: "+request.isUserInRole("usuario"));
            nextJSP = "/rutaAproteger/home.jsp";
            HttpSession sesion=request.getSession(true);
            sesion.setAttribute("usuario",p.getName());
        }
```

Esta parte del código solo se ejecuta cuando creas una sesión. Aqui puedes crear tu conexión a base de datos para almacenar lo que desees cada vez que alguien pasa por el loguin. También puedes crear una variable estática en la clase `CrearSesion` a manera de contador para llevar la cuenta.

Comment: Estaba revisando la liga, mi aplicación no es web, es de escritorio, aun asi se aplica todos los criterios `javascript`?

Comment: Eso si lo desconozco, no he hecho un loguin de escritorio

Comment: Esto esta mas orientado a web?

Comment: Si, es para web