# Como decodificar un JSON de jquery en java por medio de servlet

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp, servlets

Quiero pasar una variable JSON desde Jquery a un servlet

En mi codigo de JSP tengo un formulario

```
<div id="frmLogin" class="frmLogin">
        <label>Usuario:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtUser" class="txtUser" name="txtUser" placeholder="Usuario"/><br><br>
        <label>Contraseña:&nbsp</label>
        <input type="password" id="txtPass" class="txtPass" name="txtPass" placeholder="Contraseña"/><br>
        <label id="msgLog"></label><br>
        <button id="btnLogin">Iniciar Sesion</button>
    </div>
```

Y tengo un evento Jquery que cuando le doy click al boton todo lo que se encuentre dentro de los input se agrega a una variable tipo JSON y lo mando en un AJAX

> var sesionUsuario = JSON.stringify($('#frmLogin :input').serializeArray());

> console.log(sesionUsuario);

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {sesionUsuario: obj, key: 'inicio'},
                    url: '../iniciar',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.estado === true) {
                            location.reload();
                        } else {
                            swal({
                                title: "¡Atencion!",
                                text: "" + data.descripcion,
                                timer: 5500,
                                type: 'warning',
                                closeOnConfirm: true,
                                closeOnCancel: true
                            });
                            setTimeout(function () {

                            }, 6000);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status) {
                    }
```

Si imprimo en Jquery el JSON

> console.log(sesionUsuario);

ME imprime una cadena de texto en consola

> `[{"name":"txtUser","value":"Alberto"},{"name":"txtPass","value":"12345"}]`

A su vez esta cadena de texto se envia al servlet y extraigo la cadena de texto en una variable

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, ParseException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String key = request.getParameter("key");
    String sesionUsuario = request.getParameter("sesionUsuario");
```

Si imprimo la variable sesion Usuario me devuelve la misma cadena que imprime en la consola.

```
out.println("<h1>Usuario:  " + sesionUsuario + "</h1><br>");
```

¿Como puedo pasar ese JSON a JAVA?
¿Como puedo parsear esa cadena de texto y asi poder sacar los valores de el usuario y contraseña en variables individuales o en un array?

Comment: Tengo entendido de que existen librerias como GSON, org.json, json simple, pero solo enseñan como parsear desde el codigo pero, ¿como puedo parsear esa cadena de texto con JSONParse?

Comment: En el AJAX envio una variable obj ahi va sesioUsuario, lo habia cambiado para hacer pruebas pero siempre tengo la misma problematica

Comment: Hmm veo varios problemas en tu enfoque , primeramente si necesitas hacer submit de un formulario dentro de JSP file a un servlet no es necesario convertirlo a JSON ni hacer uso de jquery para eso tienes el campo name en tus input y el getparameter dentro del servlet para obtener los datos de tus inputs, te dejo un tutorial sobre el tema que buscas https://hmkcode.com/java-servlet-send-receive-json-using-jquery-ajax/ si despues de leer tienes dudas me avisas y trato de escribirte un ejemplo orientado a tu problema especifico.

Comment: Aunque no tiene que ver con la pregunta te puedo decir que un loguin se hace así https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/258067/3834