# Al iniciar sesión no me redirige a la página. Java Web Eclipse EE y MySQL

Tags: eclipse, mysql-workbench, java-ee

Estoy aprendiendo Java Web(aclarando que soy nuevo programando) y como proyecto final debo diseñar un pagina. En este caso quiero que al momento de logearse el usuario, lo redirija a la lista de empleados creada en MySQL.

ERROR: Solo me redirige a la misma pagina y me dice usuario y contraseña incorrectos.

NOTA ADICIONAL: Descarto que sea por algún problema de conexión puesto que ya cree un registro y listado jsp, que me funcionan sin problema.

El método ValidarEmpleado() se encarga de validar los datos.

```
public boolean ValidarEmpleado(EmpleadoDTO emp) {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement cmd;
        ResultSet rs;
        boolean validacion=false;
            
        String sql = "Select * from Empleados where UsuEmp=? and PwdEmp=?";
        try {
            conn = MySQLConexion.getConexion();
            cmd = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            cmd.setString(1, emp.getUsuEmp());
            cmd.setString(2, emp.getPwdEmp());
            rs= cmd.executeQuery();
            
            validacion = rs.next();
            
            rs.close();
            conn.close();
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        return validacion;
    }
```

LoginEmpleado.jsp es la página donde se logea el usuario.

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login de Empleados</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/loginemp.css" th:href="@{/css/index.css}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/solid.css">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>

<body>
    <div class="modal-dialog text-center">
        <div class="col-sm-8 main-section">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="col-12 user-img">
                    <img src="img/usuicon.png">
                </div>
<form class="col-12" action="LoginEmp" method="post">
    <div class="form-group" id="user-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario" id="usuemp">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="contraseña-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" id="passemp">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>  Ingresar</button>
    
</form>
<%-- Verifica si se ha establecido un mensaje de error en la solicitud --%>
<% if (request.getAttribute("mensaje") != null) { %>
  <br><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <%-- Muestra el mensaje de error --%>
    <%= request.getAttribute("mensaje") %>
  </div>
<% } %>
    <div class="col-12 forgot">
    <a href="#">¿Olvidaste la contraseña?</a>
    </div>
            </div >
        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginEmp.java es el servlet que recibe los datos ingresados en el jsp mencionado.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import beans.EmpleadoDTO;
import mantenimientos.GestionEmpleadoDTO;


@WebServlet("/LoginEmp")
public class LoginEmp extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    public LoginEmp() {     
        
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
        
    }

    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //Recibe los parámetros de LoginEmpleado.jsp
        String UsuEmp = request.getParameter("usuemp");
        String PassEmp = request.getParameter("passemp");       
        // Crea un objeto EmpleadoDTO con los datos ingresados por el usuario
        EmpleadoDTO empleado = new EmpleadoDTO();
        empleado.setUsuEmp(UsuEmp);
        empleado.setPwdEmp(PassEmp);
        //Verifica si las credenciales son válidas

        GestionEmpleadoDTO GEmpDTO = new GestionEmpleadoDTO();
        boolean isValid = GEmpDTO.ValidarEmpleado(empleado);
        //Si las credenciales son válidas, redirige al usuario a la página ListaEmp.js
        // De lo contrario, muestra un mensaje de error y vuelve a mostrar el formulario de inicio de sesión.
            if(isValid) {
                ArrayList<EmpleadoDTO> ListaEmple = GEmpDTO.ListEmployee();
                request.setAttribute("listaEmpleado", ListaEmple);
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("ListaEmp.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response); // Redirecciona al usuario a la página ListaEmp.jsp
                
            }else {
                String mensaje = "Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrectos";
                request.setAttribute("mensaje", mensaje);
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("LoginEmpleado.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response); // Muestra un mensaje de error y vuelve a mostrar el formulario de inicio de sesión
            }
            
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Un login en java se hace como dice este [hilo: ¿Cómo hacer mi login con ajax, jsp y servlets?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/258067/3834)